# I know my mnemonic phrase but #walletconnect has me stuck on "convert" page. I need help!

Tags: wallets, mobile-wallet, walletconnect

I have a very small bit of ETH from a while ago. Not worth much, but want to convert and cash out. I have never been serious about crypto, so all I know is my phrase. I booted up Wallet Connect in my previous phone and put in my mnemonic phrase. All it did was bring me to convert to EOS page and it gets stuck there. #walletconnect not helpful. Any advice for a novice?

Comment: Which wallet did you use? The wallet connect protocol doesn't have an official wallet, they provide a list of compatible wallets https://registry.walletconnect.org/wallets. It seems there's a scamwallet in the playstore with the same name, but it is unrelated to the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MyCrypto Desktop application to access with your secret recovery phrase (mnemonic). Be careful about where you type in your phrase online - as you may be getting scammed!